# Activesync wont connect to my Windows CE 6 device

Tags: usb, windows-ce, activesync

When I connect my Windows CE 6 device to my development machine I get Microsoft USB Sync to register in Windows Device manager. But I cant connect with ActiveSync for some reason. Any ideas on how to fix this?

It worked with Windows CE 5, but when we upgraded ActiveSync-functionality disappeared.

NEW UPDATE 13.34:

Error log from WCESCOMM.LOG:

```
06/07/2010 13:31:12.495 - USB: RNDIS device id ...
06/07/2010 13:31:12.964 - USB: Event 32768, name ...
06/07/2010 13:31:12.964 - USB: Device Arrival notification
06/07/2010 13:31:12.980 - ComSerial: Closed device.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.042 - UsbComm: Open device <USB>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.042 - UsbComm: Change DTR to 1.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.058 - Serial: Starting device detection at 115200.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.073 - UsbComm: Change DTR to 1.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.339 - AutobaudDetect: Found character <C>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.355 - AutobaudDetect: Found character <L>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.370 - AutobaudDetect: Found character <I>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.386 - AutobaudDetect: Found character <E>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.386 - AutobaudDetect: Found character <N>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.402 - AutobaudDetect: Found character <T>.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.402 - Serial: Unimodem handshake at 115200.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.417 - Proxy: Change connection state 1.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.417 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 5655.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.433 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3000.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.433 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3001.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.449 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3002.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.464 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3003.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.464 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3004.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.464 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3005.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.480 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3006.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.480 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3007.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.495 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3008.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.495 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3009.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.495 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3010.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.511 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3011.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.511 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3012.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.511 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3013.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.527 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3014.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.527 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3015.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.527 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3016.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.527 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3017.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.542 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3018.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.542 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3019.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.542 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3020.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.558 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3021.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.558 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3022.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.574 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3023.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.574 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3024.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.574 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3025.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.589 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3026.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.589 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3027.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.589 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3028.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.605 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3029.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.605 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3030.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.605 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 3031.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.620 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6510.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.620 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6511.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.636 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6512.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.636 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6513.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.636 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6514.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.652 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6515.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.652 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6516.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.667 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6517.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.667 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6518.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.667 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6519.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.683 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6520.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.683 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6521.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.683 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6522.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.699 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6523.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.699 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6524.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.714 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6525.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.714 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6526.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.714 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6527.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.730 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6528.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.730 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6529.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.730 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6530.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.745 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6531.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.745 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6532.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.761 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6533.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.761 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6534.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.761 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6535.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.777 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6536.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.777 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6537.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.777 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6538.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.792 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6539.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.792 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6540.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.792 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 6541.
06/07/2010 13:31:13.808 - Proxy: Created dynamic proxy on port 1026.
```

Error log from WCESMgr.log:

```
06/07/2010 13:31:51.339 **************** Logging Started ****************
06/07/2010 13:31:51.339 Process C:\Program\Microsoft ActiveSync\WCESMgr.exe  p(3040)
06/07/2010 13:31:51.339 ActiveSync second instance started, Cmd line: '/show'
06/07/2010 13:31:51.339 ActiveSync second instance exiting
06/07/2010 13:31:51.339 **************** Logging Stopped ****************
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows CE 6 and Windows CE 5 are two different things so saying that something that relates to a driver worked on one does not reflect on the other.

What exactly is the error? Does Windows (I assume XP) ask for a driver to be installed or does it say that there is an unrecognized device attached.

Are you building the OS? If so:
Having worked with Windows CE 5 you know the HW is OK so you need to make sure you have a USBFN driver that operates properly. You also need to make sure that your USB serial_class registry settings are correct and that the catalog item is included (if you are building the OS of course). Catalog item is `SYSGEN_USBFN_SERIAL`. You also need to make sure that Active Synce is included in the OS (`SYSGEN_AS_BASE`).

Update:
So, you are the OEM. If you say that you see the dialer start and stop on the Windows CE device you can look at your debug serial to look for an error code. It might be that your RAS phone book entry is not correct.
Try the following:

- Check on the Desktop to see whether it identifies an unidentified USB device. At least you will know that the desktop tried to communicate with the device and failed to retreive the descriptors.
- Make sure that the Serial_class is the one that Windows CE tries to use. You do this by settings the following registry setting (Windows CE 6 does not support ActiveSync over RNDIS):
  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers]
  "DefaultClientDriver"="Serial_Class"`
- You should have an entry for `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers\Serial_Class]` once you include the serial class catalog item. This entry is copied from `WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\FILES\common.reg` in case you are not setting something of your own in one of your OSDesing registry files.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the input! We are building our own version of Windows CE 6. I'm not in charge of the OS build though, but I work closely with the guy who is. (The guy who made our CE 5 build has quit a year ago or so. )
I just checked with him and both of the catalog items that you mentioned were included. Do we need to do any special registry settings for usb serial_class to be registered or will the included catalog item take care of that?

Comment: We do not get any specific error through Active sync. The device just doesn't connect. On the device we see a connectionbox popping up and disappearing just as fast with a beep. Then nothing.
See my original post for error logs...

Comment: Hi again!

We checked the registry and found both entries. We also tried to create a new network connection on the device, binding it to COM4 and choosing it in "Settings-Control Panel-PC Connection". Now
The device and windows seem to interact some more. 
The device gets to Device connected, but on the PC-side Activesync gets stuck on connecting, then the device exits the connection and after a while the PC pops up a screen saying that Activesync could not connect to the Windows mobile-device.

Any ideas on this one?

I've updated the output from the logfiles.

Comment: Here is some Voodoo to try ;) : Try to attach it to another Desktop. Try to reboot the Desktop machine. Do not use any extension cables for the USB or hubs -> connect the module directly to the port on the Desktop.

Comment: Yeah, we tried on a new freshly installed windows machine. Didn't work. I've also tried sacrificing a chicken just recently while chanting the EULA backwards while my colleague banged on a bongo drum. ...and it didn't work either. 

So I'm going to try a tip found on a forum which said that I should try to revert to a older version of activesync now and see what happens...

If you've got any other ideas I'll happily try them out. :-)

Comment: You should be working with AS 4.5. You can also try to enable the Mass Storage Class or the RNDIS just to make sure that your USBFn driver is functioning properly. What platform are you using (what CPU)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete the old connection and start a new one?  I've had similar issues with CE 5.  That sometimes worked as well as just rebooting everything.

Comment: Delete connection? I'm using USB, I shouldn't have to setup a network connection .... or?

Comment: I meant in the activesync program on windows.  It keeps track of what device you are connected to.  I also remember forcefully killing the activesync process sometimes.  I'm merely going off memory on what I used to do when developing for a mobile.